# How to find the y-intercept using sympy?

Tags: python, math, numpy, sympy

```
x = Symbol('x')
f = x**2-3

def return_y_intercept(f):
   return [the y-intercepts]
```

How is it possible using something like the structure above write a function that returns the y-intercepts of it's argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The y-intercept just means that you substitute 0 for x, so just do `f.subs(x, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sympy.coeff`, [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#c), so like this:

Y-intercept as Coordinates

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
f = x**2-3

def return_y_intercept(f):
   return [0,f.coeff(x,0)] #return coordintes of y-intercept

print return_y_intercept(f)
```

Output:

```
0,-3
```

Y-intercept:

```
from sympy import Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
f = x**2-3

def return_y_intercept(f):
   return [f.coeff(x,0)] #return just the y-intercept

print return_y_intercept(f)
```

Output:

```
-3
```

try it on the online sympy interpreter [here](http://live.sympy.org)

Comment: This is excessively complicated. Check the other answer.

Comment: @Krasranov it is the same thing, just using `sympys builtin` the `coeff`, OP asked fo, how to find yhe y intercept using sympy.

Comment: But it works only for polynomials and hides the intention behind the code (the intention is to find the value at x=0; the straightforward way to do it is simply to evaluate it)